# Height of Rotated Square

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a square of sides 30 cm. Like in the image shown here:
[square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgC5D.png)

Now if I rotated the square clockwise by 30 degrees. What will its height be from the bottom?
[square rotated by 30 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2lv8.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you rotate it by $\theta$ degrees your height will be $\underbrace{30 \sqrt{2}}_{\text{diag. length}} \times \cos(45° - \theta)$

Comment: Thank you, Jean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as the second image suggests you are rotating the square not about its center but about its lower corner (like tilting up a box on the floor), [image: height of rotated square] then the height we're looking for is $$FA'+A'D=FD$$

And since in right triangle $A'DC$ the side opposite the $30^o$ angle is half the hypotenuse, then$$A'D=15\mathrm{cm}$$And since triangles $A'DC$ and $EFA'$ are congruent, then $\angle FEA'=\angle DA'C=60^o$, making$$FA'=15\sqrt3=25.98\mathrm{cm}$$Therefore$$FD=25.98+15=40.98 \mathrm{cm}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer edward. I initially thought like this but was not sure about it.